# Skip DHCP discover and go right to DHCP request

Tags: networking, dhcp

When booting the DHCP client sends a DHCP discover before the DHCP request. This is in contrast to Windows where an optimistic approach is done, first attempting to send a DHCP request for the desired IP address (i.e. last).

By sending a request first one can attempt to use the desired IP addresses that have been released or are expiring but might nevertheless be available. If the DHCP client gets acceptance for the release everything is good, if not one must start over again with discovery.

Is this achievable by configuration?

Comment: Typically, even with a discover, if the old IP address has not been re-assigned in the interim, which it only would have been if it had to due to the pool being exhausted, the client will get the same IP address. However, it depends on the DHCP server implementation.

Comment: Applies to the most DHCP server, but unfortunately not all DHCP servers including at least one from Palo Alto @DougSmythies